# How to make the for loop merge new values across sheets?

Tags: vba, loops, excel, merge

I had someone help me make the initial code for this, Im trying to modify it however its wrong.

I need to compare sheet 2 in a spreadsheet to sheets 4 to 10 and if the values of row e or b do not match any other row. copy the entire row to the bottom of sheet 1.

This is what I have so far but the value isn't being set to true and it prints after every sheet. I'm stick

```
 Sub Button13() 'merge

    Dim lastSourceRow As Long, LastTargetRow As Long, allSheets As Long, lastSheet As Long
    Dim source As String, TARGET As Integer
    Dim tempVal As String, tempValE, tempValT
    Dim tRow As Long, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, nRow As Long
    Dim match As Boolean


    source = "Sheet2"
    lastSheet = "10"

    lastSourceRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For allSheets = 1 To lastSheet


    TARGET = allSheets
    LastTargetRow = Sheets(TARGET).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 2 To lastSourceRow     'Loop through Rows on currentsheet
        Count = "0"
        match = False                 'Reset boolean test for each new row
        tempVal = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "B").Value      'Assign the tempValue to compare
        tempValE = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "E").Value

        For tRow = 2 To LastTargetRow   'Loop through entire target sheet
        tempValT = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value
            If (allSheets <> 2 Or allSheets <> 3) And tempVal = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value And tempValE = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "E").Value Then
            match = True
            ElseIf (allSheets <> 2 Or allSheets <> 3) And tempVal = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value And tempValE = "" Then
            match = True
            ElseIf (allSheets <> 2 Or allSheets <> 3) And tempVal = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value Then
            match = True
            'ElseIf Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "G").Value < DateAdd("m", -5, Date) Then
            'match = True
            End If
        Next tRow


        If match = False Then         'No Match found, copy row
            nRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            For lCol = 1 To 26       'Copy entire row by looping through 6 columns
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRow, lCol).Value = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
            Next lCol
        End If

    Next lRow
    Next allSheets

End Sub
```

Comment: feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

problem 1: you reset `match = False` inside the `lRow` loop, this must be inside the `tRow` loop, otherwise if the first `match = True` hits then `match` is never reset

problem 2: `If match = False Then` can't be entered because it is outside of your `tRow` loop. so `match` is set inside the loop but can not be reached by `If match = False Then`

so the working code should be

```
Sub Button13() 'merge

    Dim lastSourceRow As Long, LastTargetRow As Long, allSheets As Long, lastSheet As Long
    Dim source As String, TARGET As Integer
    Dim tempVal As String, tempValE, tempValT
    Dim tRow As Long, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, nRow As Long
    Dim match As Boolean


    source = "Sheet2"
    lastSheet = "10"

    lastSourceRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For allSheets = 1 To lastSheet


    TARGET = allSheets
    LastTargetRow = Sheets(TARGET).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 2 To lastSourceRow     'Loop through Rows on currentsheet
        Count = "0"

        tempVal = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "B").Value      'Assign the tempValue to compare
        tempValE = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "E").Value

        For tRow = 2 To LastTargetRow   'Loop through entire target sheet
        tempValT = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value
            If (allSheets <> 2 Or allSheets <> 3) And tempVal = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value And tempValE = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "E").Value Then
            match = True
            ElseIf (allSheets <> 2 Or allSheets <> 3) And tempVal = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value And tempValE = "" Then
            match = True
            ElseIf (allSheets <> 2 Or allSheets <> 3) And tempVal = Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "B").Value Then
            match = True
            'ElseIf Sheets(TARGET).Cells(tRow, "G").Value < DateAdd("m", -5, Date) Then
            'match = True
            End If


        If match = False Then         'No Match found, copy row
            nRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            For lCol = 1 To 26       'Copy entire row by looping through 6 columns
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(nRow, lCol).Value = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
            Next lCol
        End If

'2 moved lines
match = False                 'Reset boolean test for each new row
Next tRow

    Next lRow
    Next allSheets

End Sub
```

Comment: haven't checked where the problem is yet but it doesnt return any values when i run the macro with test variables.

Comment: how does your source look like? with my test variables is all working

Comment: my code's super messy but basically its printing every value like 3 000 times (Every time i t loops through the tRow loop) regardless if it matches or not? trying to debug now.. the loop never sets itself to true for some reason.